# How to get a JSON Object from a Jersey POST Response

Tags: android, json, spring, rest, jersey-2.0

I am working at the REST API for a new Social Network Android App at the moment using Spring Android for the Client and Spring Boot for the Server.

I am having trouble securing the Server using Spring Security, because i don't understand how to use it properly. After reading tons of sample apps i gave up on spring security and found [this](http://www.developerscrappad.com/1814/java/java-ee/rest-jax-rs/java-ee-7-jax-rs-2-0-simple-rest-api-authentication-authorization-with-custom-http-header/) tutorial on how to secure APIs using Jersey.

Instead of javascript i am using the Jersey Client API to test the implementation

```
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/demo-business-resource/login");

    Invocation.Builder invoBuilder = target.request();
    invoBuilder.header("service_key", "3b91cab8-926f-49b6-ba00-920bcf934c2a");

      MultivaluedMap formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
      formData.add("username", "username2");
      formData.add( "password", "passwordForUser2");
      Response response = invoBuilder.post(Entity.form(formData));
      System.out.println(response);
response.getEntity();
```

The POST request is successful, but i cant get the JSON object which should be the Entity of the Response. response.getEntity(); returns a HttpUrlConnector Object.

Here the related Server Code

```
@POST
@Path( "login" )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Response login(
    @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
    @FormParam( "username" ) String username,
    @FormParam( "password" ) String password ) {

    DemoAuthenticator demoAuthenticator = DemoAuthenticator.getInstance();
    String serviceKey = httpHeaders.getHeaderString( DemoHTTPHeaderNames.SERVICE_KEY );

    try {
        String authToken = demoAuthenticator.login( serviceKey, username, password );

        JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        jsonObjBuilder.add( "auth_token", authToken );
        JsonObject jsonObj = jsonObjBuilder.build();

        return getNoCacheResponseBuilder( Response.Status.OK ).entity( jsonObj.toString() ).build();

    } catch ( final LoginException ex ) {
        JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        jsonObjBuilder.add( "message", "Problem matching service key, username and password" );
        JsonObject jsonObj = jsonObjBuilder.build();

        return getNoCacheResponseBuilder( Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED ).entity( jsonObj.toString() ).build();
    }
}


private Response.ResponseBuilder getNoCacheResponseBuilder( Response.Status status ) {
    CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
    cc.setNoCache( true );
    cc.setMaxAge( -1 );
    cc.setMustRevalidate( true );

    return Response.status( status ).cacheControl( cc );
}
```

I am new to Jersey and i only want to use it to generate the Authentication Token, because i get 404 Not Found errors using Spring. (I am working with spring-jersery )
Here my Spring approach of the client

```
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    params.add("service_key", "3b91cab8-926f-49b6-ba00-920bcf934c2a");

    MultiValueMap<String,String> formData=new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,String>();
    formData.add("username", "username2");
    formData.add( "password", "passwordForUser2");
    Model_LoginProfile log = new Model_LoginProfile();
    log.setLoginName("username2");
    log.setPassword("passwordForUser2");

     HttpHeaders requestHeaders=new HttpHeaders();
      requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
      requestHeaders.set("service_key", "3b91cab8-926f-49b6-ba00-920bcf934c2a");

      HttpEntity<Model_LoginProfile> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Model_LoginProfile>(log, requestHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<String> result = template.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/demo-business-resource/login", requestEntity, String.class);
    }
```

Maybe someone has a fix for that as well. :)

Thanks in advance